# Python pandas slicing multiple row values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

trying to filter out 'chen3','abc1','wei3' in a column
tsg.loc[tsg['Trader']=="chen3",'abc1','wei3']

please advise

Comment: `tsg.loc[~tsg['Trader'].isin(['chen3','abc1','wei3'])]`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, try to display more of your code and what you are trying to do. In case you're trying to split a string in Python take a look at the [Split method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

```
tsg[(tsg.Trader != "chen3") & (tsg.Trader != "abc") & (tsg.Trader != "wei3")]
```